# tex4ebook, use paragraph and subsubsubsection in TOC

Tags: tex4ht, tex4ebook

@michal.h21 EDIT2: I updates all the repositories from https://github.com/michal-h21. It works .
I edited the code which does not work

this is what I do. I copy your `cfg.cfg`, I create the `myfile.tex` and run

```
tex4ebook   -l -f epub -m -t myfile.tex
```

this is the simple code

```
    \documentclass{article} 

\makeatletter
\def\subsubsubsection{%
\penalty-9999
\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{0em}{0.1\parskip}{1em}{%
\small\rmfamily\mdseries\itshape}
}
\makeatother


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

    \begin{document}
    \tableofcontents
    \section{first seciton}
    \subsection{first subsection}
    \subsubsection{first subSUBsection}
    \subsubsubsection{first subSUBsubsection}

    my subsubsubsection here

    \paragraph{first para}

    werfj

    \section{second section}
    \section{third seciton}
    \end{document}
```

it works well now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is quite a lot of requirements, I hope I didn't forget about anything. I've moved your code from the TeX file to the `.cfg` file, which is more flexible. You also need the development version of `tex4ebook`, because the version in distributions has fixed level of sections which go to the `NCX` file (it is used in the side menu).

```
\Preamble{xhtml,sections+}

\NewSection\subsubsubsection{\theparagraph}

\Configure{subsubsubsection}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\IgnorePar\Tg<subsubsubsection id="subsubsubsection.\theparagraph">}
{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\IgnorePar\Tg</subsubsubsection>}
{\addtocounter{paragraph}{1}
 \HCode{<font size="+0">}%
 \NoFonts\HCode{<span class="it">}%
 \TitleMark%
 \HCode{\Hnewline}}%
{\HCode{</span>}\EndNoFonts%
 \HCode{</font>}%
 \HCode{\Hnewline}%
 \par\IgnoreIndent\ShowPar%
}

\Css{span.it{font-style:italic;}}
\ConfigureMark{subsubsubsection}{\theparagraph~@@@~}
\Configure{toToc}{subsubsubsection}{paragraph}


\ConfigureToc{paragraph}
{~~~\HCode{<span class="paragraphToc" >}}{~@@@~}{}{\HCode{</span>}\HCode{<br />\Hnewline}}

% \ConfigureToc{subsubsubsection}
% {~~~\HCode{<span class="subsubsubsectionToc" >}}{~@@@~}{}{\HCode{</span>}\HCode{<br />\Hnewline}}

\def\newncxtox#1#2{%
  \ConfigureToc{#1}%
  {\closelevels{#2}%
  \csname a:NavSection\endcsname\csname Ncx:Mark\endcsname}
  {\csname c:NavSection\endcsname~@@@~}
  {}
  {\csname b:NavSection\endcsname%
    \finishtoclevel{#1}%
  }
}

\begin{document}
\expandafter\def\csname ncx:title\endcsname{%
  \HCode{<docTitle>\Hnewline<text>}\Title\HCode{</text>\Hnewline</docTitle>\Hnewline}
  \newncxtox{paragraph}{paragraph}
}
\EndPreamble
```

Let's dive into the code a little bit:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,sections+}
```

You will get section links thanks to `sections+` option.

```
\ConfigureMark{subsubsubsection}{\theparagraph~@@@~}
\Configure{toToc}{subsubsubsection}{paragraph}
```

First configuration will add the `@@@` after the subsubsubsection counter, the second will include it in the TOC, using configuration for `\paragraph`. So `\ConfigureToc{paragraph}` will work for both commands.

```
\def\newncxtox#1#2{%
  \ConfigureToc{#1}%
  {\closelevels{#2}%
  \typeout{konfigurujeme nxc title #1, - #2}
  \csname a:NavSection\endcsname\csname Ncx:Mark\endcsname}
  {\csname c:NavSection\endcsname~@@@~}
  {}
  {\csname b:NavSection\endcsname%
    \finishtoclevel{#1}%
  }
}

\begin{document}
\expandafter\def\csname ncx:title\endcsname{%
  \HCode{<docTitle>\Hnewline<text>}\Title\HCode{</text>\Hnewline</docTitle>\Hnewline}
  \newncxtox{paragraph}{paragraph}
}
```

This is a dirty hack to get your `@@@` into the `NCX` file, this isn't normally configurable. The `\newnctox` command is modeled after internal `tex4ebook` command, which takes care of correct hierarchy of entries in the `NCX` file. It is a list of entries at the same on lower level than the current sectioning. Because `\subsubsubsection` is configured as `\paragraph` and because it is lowest part of the hierarchy, the only element in the closing list is the `paragraph` itself.

Here are some results:

[image]

and the document:

[image]

Finally, the ebook viewer:

[image]

Comment: It works, but is there a way to put the flag `sections+` in the `.tex` file, instead of relying on a `.cfg` file ?

Comment: I have found a bug related to your hack for the yellow TOC. If I add * a second section*, then the bug appears and I have the message `HTML Tidy for Windows version 5.3.9
Ligne: 40 Col: 1 - Error:unexpected </navMap> in <navPoint>
Ligne: 41 Col: 1 - Error:unexpected </ncx> in <navPoint>
Tidy ncx 2
Tidy opf 0`. is it possible for the solution to work with *custom sections*, entered via `\sectionABC` and `\sectionDEF` and so on ?

Comment: @HarryLotter could you please update your question with code that causes the error?

Comment: @HarryLotter it should work now.